# how to add Android platform into Netbeans 7.0, after installed android plugin

Tags: android, plugins, netbeans-7

I installed Android plugin using Tools/Plugins/Settings and copied the link there, and so on. In the next step, I would get to Tools/Java Platforms/Add platform, then it pope up with "1.Choose the platform folder" instead of "1.Select platform type". Because of that, I couldn't proceed into the next steps.

I tried to remove and reinstall Java SDK and Netbeans several times using different methods. But nothing has changed. I really appreciate the answer.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add android platform in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017043/cannot-add-android-platform-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 2):

You are following one of outdated install guides/tutorials. Current version of Android support only needs to know where your Android SDK is. Go to Tools | Options | Misc | Android and set the location there. You can find more details at http://www.nbandroid.org/

It can even detect this location automatically if you open some configured project but it seems this is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the plugin the sdk and the platform then choose from netbeans file new project android project next choose the target platform listed under target name input package name and voila.

Comment: Thanks for your response though. I have decided to use Eclipse instead of Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the platform is a seperate step. Look in the sdk folder and read the readme. On linux, at least, it says to run the "android" program, which is in the tools folder. After installing the platform through this it should let you progress in setting up netbeans.

It's not an obvious step if you're a noob and head straight to google with "setup netbeans for android"