# Cannot add android platform in NetBeans

Tags: android, plugins, netbeans, platform

I followed one or two tutorials on installing NBAndroid plugin and setting platform, but I encountered a problem. After installing the plugin and setting SDK location (in Tools/Options/Misc/Android), when I wanted to add the android platform (Tools/Java Platforms/Add Platform...) it showed me a window with "1. Choose platform folder..." instead of "1. Choose platform type..." (as in a few tutorials). Because of this I can't add the platform (when I choose the platform folder the "next" and "finish" buttons are still inactive).

NetBeans 7.0.1, NBAndroid (latest, not really sure about the number), Windows 7 64. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, someone else helped me and I know the answer. Turns out... I've already done everything I needed to. Adding Android platform is deprecated and now providing path to android SDK is all that is needed after installing the plugin. Now I have "Android" project type in New Projects... but I just didin't see it before. :P

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted so others will know that the issue was resolved (yes you can mark your own answers as accepted).

Comment: I was going to but got message that I can't do it for 2 days since sending the post. :P